# Ending task manager

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, taskmanager

in cmd, if I enter the code

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.ex
```

it ends explorer. But if I enter

```
taskkill /f /im taskmgr.exe
```

It says the access was denied and the only way to do it is open cmd as admin. Is there any way to do it without open as admin, or is there a way that when you open a batch script, it automatically opens as administrator ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: right-click the file and click run as administrator. Also, wrong place to ask this question, probably more of a super user question.

Comment: yes, I got that but that isn't the question, I asked if there was a way AROUND using admin rights. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using this template for admin tasks a while. Hope it helps you.

```
:: Verify we don't have administrator privileges
net file >nul 2>&1
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" goto :admin

:: Execute VB script to execute the script with elevated privileges
(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~dpf0", "", "%~dp0", "runas", 1
) > "%temp%\get-privileges.vbs"

"%temp%\get-privileges.vbs"
exit /b

:admin
::Administrator work here!!
```